# Inline User Defined Function for a view having parameters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using an openquery to get my data. Because of the length of my query which exceeds 8000 characters, I am using this approach :

```
DECLARE @myStatement VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @myStatement 'SELECT * FROM Employee...'
EXECUTE (@myStatement) AT [MyLinkedServer]
```

Knowing that it is not possible to use variables in a view, I am trying to use a User Defined function that returns a table like below :

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.EmployeeDetailsForHR
                 (@myStatement VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS TABLE

AS RETURN(EXECUTE (@myStatement) AT [MyLinkedServer]);

SELECT *
FROM dbo.EmployeeDetailsForHR('SELECT * FROM Employee...');
```

But my CREATE FUNCTION isn't correct. What is the correct syntax in my case?

Comment: You can't use dynamic SQL in user defined functions.

Comment: @ZoharPeled my statement is a simple select query

Comment: You can have a few parameters with a function, but not the entire SQL command. As Zohar said, if you want full dynamic control you need an SP.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the statement is, it's dynamic and therefor can't be used inside a user defined function.

Comment: @ZoharPeled what do you mean by dynamic in this context ?

Comment: An sql statement stored in a variable executed with the `EXEC` function.